# Your Instant App APKs have version code 'X' which is already in use

Tags: android, versioning, android-instant-apps

I have an instant app running in production which has a version code of **1** and a version name of **1.0**:

[image: instant app]

And now I wanted to upload a newer version of the instant app APKs, but I was held off due to this error that the Google Play Console prompts me:

[image: upload error]

I tried changing the version code & name in the **build.gradle** file of the installed app's module, but to no avail. I also tried adding this piece of code :

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 2
        versionName '1.1'
    }
}
```

to the **build.gradle** file of the instant app's module, but it still yields the same error. 
So my question is, how can I change the version code & the version name of an instant app ?

Comment: Don't you need to change the `versionCode` and `versionName` in the AndroidManifest.xml?
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html

Comment: I've never really changed version codes before through the manifest as it seems like Gradle is the way, but I don't think in this case it would work, since the problem is instant-app-related, and considering the fact that the instant app module has no AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution. I had to change the version code & name in all of the **build.gradle** files of the feature modules (including the **base** one). 
If you miss a certain feature module, you'll get this error in the Play Console:

[image: error]